# How to send a parameter from a .NET Rest Client Method using GET

Tags: .net, rest, get

My Code:

```
    protected void btFeedsPorFechaPublicacion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient proxy = new WebClient();
        byte[] data = proxy.DownloadData(new Uri("http://tribilin.codefactorycr.com/SORSSJ/rest/servicio/ObtenerFeedsRecientes"));

        System.Text.UTF7Encoding utf = new UTF7Encoding();
        string s = utf.GetString(data);

        FeedEstructuradoC[] d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FeedEstructuradoC[]>(s);

    }
```

The Method ObtenerFeedsRecientes needs a param called "tag" how should i modify btFeedsPorFechaPublicacion to acomplished that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing i had to do was this:

```
byte[] data = proxy.DownloadData(new Uri("http://tribilin.codefactorycr.com/SORSSJ/rest/servicio/ObtenerFeedsRecientes/" + tbTag.Text));
```

In Get the param is assumed to be send without specifying its name! i didn´t know that. 
Hope this helps someone in the future ;)